# How should a question that covers more than one topic be managed

Tags: discussion, editing

For example this question would benefit from being 2 separate questions, one about DDOS and one about Tezos ports - [How to secure baking node from attacks like DDOS?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/134/how-to-secure-baking-node-from-attacks-like-ddos)

Should the original question be closed and two separate questions created or is there another more appropriate way?

Comment: This question doesn’t really look like it’s multiple questions for me. Will answer for general case later.

Comment: I also believe this question is not covering multiple distinct topics to me. Setting up ports for baking is essentially a security question

Answer (score 1):

When a question is actually asking 2 or more different things, it should be closed as "too broad". This is the description of it (emphasis mine):

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.** See the [How to Ask](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

The question you linked to seems to be asking multiple similar but different questions. It should be closed as "Too Broad".